# What does the phrase "notch your arrows" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of "notch your arrows" mentioned [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=04LoCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA365&lpg=PA365&dq=%22notch%20your%20arrows%22&source=bl&ots=hw0dC_c0Of&sig=ACfU3U3y4-rJv3Cw4-e24EjuaXu-iM7IbQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_j_OLo7vmAhWqxDgGHWt2Bu0Q6AEwAnoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22notch%20your%20arrows%22&f=false).

I found the lexical meanings of the word notch [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/notch), but they don't seem to fit in the given context.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

In the text you refer to from the book, **Druids of the Faerie**, the command to the bowmen is for them to take an arrow (presumably from their quivers) and to fit the notch (the cut at the feathered end of the arrow) to the bowstring in readiness to fire.

Modern archery books refer to this as **nocking**.

According to the book sourced below:

**Nocking the arrow is the process of holding the arrow so you can snap the nock onto the bowstring. It also means checking that the arrow's index vanes or fletching are orientated on the bowstring for proper clearance as the arrow passes the riser.**

Other articles refer to **nocking** as actually fitting the notch to the bowstring.

Thus both **to nock** (and in your text to **notch your arrows**) means preparing to fire the arrow.

http://www.learn-archery.com/nocking-the-arrow.html
https://wikidiff.com/notch/nock

Comment: You don't "fire" an arrow.

Comment: Some people evidently do (admittedly a minority) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shoot+the+arrow%2Cfire+the+arrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshoot%20the%20arrow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfire%20the%20arrow%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Sorry  meant you *shouldn't* say fire an arrow.  Obviously lots of people do, but the use is considered incorrect by some people. You fire a gun, but you shoot an arrow.  I'm just in a nerdy and pedantic mood.  Anyway +1 for "nock".

Comment: No argument. Been reflecting on the use myself. How about: **He was struck by an arrow fired through the open window?**

Comment: @JamesK and RonaldSole, I can't help but ask if both nock and notch (the verb forms) are not common usage. I know their meaning clearly from watching shows - exactly as both of you point out, but I can't find "nock/notch your/their arrows" in Ngram.

Comment: No, I did some hasty reading on modern archery!

Comment: @JamesK I agree. The first guns were set off by literally applying fire to the powder; the sense of the word has extended from 'set fire to' to mean 'aim at'.

Answer (score 1):

It means "to fit an arrow to a bow, by means of the notch cut in the end of the arrow."

Notching your arrow is the first step to shooting it. You notch, then pull back and release to let the arrow fly

> When you're sure the glue is completely dry, gently flex the tip and the feathers to test their strength. If they're securely attached and don't budge at all, your arrow's ready to fire! **Notch your arrow** in your bow, pull the bowstring back, aim, and let your arrow fly! Never shoot your arrow at people or animals - even stone age arrows can seriously hurt someone - after all, they were originally used for hunting.

https://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-Arrow